# Chrome display is Polish despite setting for English language

Tags: google-chrome, language

My language is set to English (U.S) in Chrome, yet it is displaying in Polish.  Why?  How do I fix this (again, it was already, and still is, set to English in settings.)

Comment: What is in Polish? The Chrome interface or web pages? I believe the Chrome setting is for web pages and the Chrome interface itself uses the System setting.

Comment: Read this: http://support.google.com/chromeos/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1059490

Answer (score 1):

I have had trouble in the past with Chrome changing font styles (I wasn't keen on everything being italicized). The easiest way to fix this sort of problem is to uninstall. You can back up your bookmarks before you do so however (to do so without utilizing the log in to Chrome feature, go [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en)).

Often even just uninstalling Chrome will not fix this setting. It takes a more thorough approach. My solution was to uninstall using [CcLeaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner). I would uninstall from the Control Panel, then go into Program Files and make sure that no Chrome folders remain. Then run Ccleaner and run the registry cleaner in Ccleaner. After all of this your install of Chrome should be fresh; thus alleviating the Polish.